how to get data in many to many relation in laravel
I want to use many-to-many relationship for the first time, initially I had four one-to-many relationships and all the information was displayed in index form. Then I decided to write the table of offices in many-to-many with tasks table, so I changed the codes as follows:
pivot table migration:
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('office_task', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('office_id');
            $table->foreign('office_id')->references('id')->on('offices')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('task_id');
            $table->foreign('task_id')->references('id')->on('tasks')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });   
    }

in task model:
public function Office(): BelongsToMany 
    {
        // return $this->belongsTo(Office::class, 'office_id'); 
        return $this->belongsToMany(Office::class); 

    }

in office model :
public function tasks(): BelongsToMany    
    {       
        // return $this->hasMany(Task::class,'office_id');                       
        return $this->belongsToMany(Task::class);
    }

in controller with three one-to-many and one many-to-many relations:
public function index()
    {

        $tasks = Task::where('type', 0)
        ->with(['Office', 'Commander', 'Status', 'Priority'])
        ->Sortable()
        ->paginate(8);
        
        return view('taskmanager.tasks.index',compact('tasks'));
    }

and in index form (view):
@foreach($tasks as $item)
    <tr>
    <td>{{$item->id}}</td>
    <td>{{$item->Caption}}</td>
    <td>{{$item->Commander->Desc}}</td>
    <td>{{$item->Priority->Desc}}</td> 
    <td>{{$item->Status->Desc}}</td>
    <td>{{$item->office->caption}}</td>    //line with error
    <td>
      
 </tr>    
 @endforeach

but in line {{$item->office->caption}} I get an error :Property [caption] does not exist on this collection instance.
As I said before, I don't have this error in one-to-many mode, how can I edit and run it?

Because offices is collection, not one office

how to solve it

Return belongsTo relation instead of belongsToMany

A belongsToMany relationship models a many to many link between your models. That means your Tasks can have many offices, and your Offices many tasks, and this implies that now those relationships are going always to return a collection of items no matter what. If that's what you really want then you also need to rename the relation in Task from Office() to Offices(). To print the captions from all the related offices you can use $item->Offices->implode('caption', ', ').

Another question: I changed the caption line to {{$item->offices->implode('pivot',', ',)}} and it displays all offices related to a task, also I have an additional field called "main_office" in the pivot table and I want to display only offices whose main_office field is one, How should I change the code to not display the tenth and the rest that have zero value

To add additional constraints to the relationship's query you can use a lambda when specifying the eager loads, e.g.: ->with['offices' => fn (Builder $q) => $q->where('main_office', 1)->orWhere(...), 'Commander', ...]. Refer to the docs for more info.
